# Captcha image not displaying on server using php

Tags: php, captcha

I am creating a form with captcha . But my problem is that the captcha is working fine in `localhost` but not in the `remote server` . But when loading the page I can see the image but on fully loaded page I cannot see the image (it shows only a broken image).
Here is my HTML Code :

```
<input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:11px;"/>
<img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>"alt="verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" style=" float:left; clear:both; "   />
```

and my PHP Code

```
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

 $width = 50;
 $height = 24;

 $my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

 imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
   $x = rand(0,$width-1);
   $y = rand(0,$height-1);
   imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
}

$x = rand(1,10);
$y = rand(1,10);

$rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);
setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));
imagejpeg($my_image);
imagedestroy($my_image);
```

I have also tested GD installed and it's installed.
what I am doing wrong any help will be appreciated

Comment: What's the pb? You forgot the `;` at the end

Comment: @ Zl3n for your comment I think it's the problem with the connection

Comment: It worked for me in local

Comment: me too . But not in the remote server it might be the problem with the remote server